# How to make weights continous with db_update?

Tags: 7, database

With pure MySQL, I can do something like:

```
SET @weight:=0;
UPDATE mymodule_table
  SET mymodule_weight=@weight:=@weight+1
  ORDER BY mymodule_weight, mymodule_id;
```

Is there a Drupal way to achieve similar result? Can I avoid calls to [`db_query`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) and push it with [`db_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7) or [`db_merge`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_merge/7)?

MySQL solution adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617100/2389310).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the expression is no problem, but neither [`UpdateQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/class/UpdateQuery/7) nor [`MergeQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/class/MergeQuery/7) implement an `orderBy()` method. Neither will support setting a local variable first either, as far as I can tell (I'm not even sure a standard query will let you do that actually).

So I think it's safe to say that the answer is no, unless you subclass either `UpdateQuery` or `MergeQuery`, and add the sorting and variable declaration functionality yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I'm disappointed, but at least I wasn't blind not to see how to do it. I will not accept for now, maybe there is a way without variable that can be done "Drupal way". Feel free to remind me after a week or two (but I guess you may be too busy to do that).